# How to create text field with label like Material UI using Swift UI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I'm creating an application using Swift UI. I receiva a layout in Figma and the Text Field needs to be like Material UI, with the label above the border.

[Material UI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFUo5.png)

The border needs to be roundered. I tried use ZStack, but I don't know how put the Text like the label of Material UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the *ZStack* approach, hope it helps you.

Please note that you have to **adjust** the float numbers conforming your project:

```
struct MaterialTextFieldView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            TextField("Hello world", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .frame(width: 200)
            
            Text("Required *")
                .font(.caption2)
                .offset(x: -55, y: -16)
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks like your prototype.